# How can I save / access credentials in credential manager from a remote machine?

Tags: security, credentials, credentials-manager, share-credentials

I have to save credentials using a service account onto a remote machine and also should be able to access the credentials from remote machine using the service credentials.

I have tried using credman.ps1 script not able to do it.

**Is there a way that I can do this using cmdkey exe I can execute the same script from my c# code**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into this. The link has manual steps on how to achieve it. I'm looking for something which can be done using the scripts

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the answer I highlighted is a command-line command, so you could easily script that (stick in a batch file, done).  If you're looking for a C#-specific way of doing it, then you are asking on the the wrong site (programming questions go on StackOverflow.com). :)